# Error: Class 'Google\Spreadsheet\Service Request Factory' not found

Tags: google-spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

Пытаюсь записать данные в Гугл таблицу, делаю это на новом сервере (на старом работает).
Установил компостер
Сделал

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

Запускаю скрипт и получаю

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory' not found
```

Напоминаю - на старом сервере все рабоате.
Что не так? Неправильно как то установился google/apiclient ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было еще установить

```
composer require asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client
```